# Using Boto3 and Python How Make a Folder Public

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I want to make a folder called `img` that already exists within my private bucket **public**. I'm using Boto3. I just want to make this folder public not anything else using a script..

This is how I'm currently connecting to the bucket and how far I have got....

```
ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxx'
ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxx'
bucket_name = 'mybucket'
sourceDir = "../../docs/buildHTML/html/"
destDir = ''

r = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
```

So I have the bucket and this works. How do I now make the folder `img` that already exists public?

Comment: As an aside, try to provide IAM credentials through an IAM role or environment variables or ~/.boto config file rather than hard-coding them in your source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a policy to the bucket, something like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicReadImages",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/abc/img/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can do this through the AWS console, or any of the SDKs. In [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketpolicy), I think you do it like this:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

response = bucket.put(
    Policy = '<policy string here>'
)
```